# Which category of a statement initialization is?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, initialization, while-loop

**The Question :**

1. In programming , assignment statement is an expression , but how about initialization?Is it an expression??
2. the parentheses of a `while` loop should contain an expression , so i try to put an initialization into it , and the compiler prompt me an error , this shows initialization is not an expression.
3. To further prove it , i try the `for` loop , and i do this `for(int num = 3 ; num2 = 4 ; num3 = 5)`.Surprisingly the compiler give me errors again.
4. So if an initialization is not an expression , what kind of statement it is??

*Thanks for spending time reading my question*

Comment: It depends on whether you are using C++ or C. You put both tags on your question!

Comment: good point @JoelSpolsky. The wonderful thing about C is that the *[K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)* book is so short that you can quickly read and understand the whole language. *[Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html)* is longer, but it isn't hard to understand if you have a solid grounding in *K&R*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both C and C++, assignment is an expression. E.g. `a = 5` is an *assignment-expression*.

In both C and C++ you can use any expression followed by a semi-colon where *statement* is required - such as the body of a function. This type of *statement* is an *expression-statement*. (Technially, you can leave out the expression entirely. `;` is a degenerate *expression-statement*.)

You can only use a declaration where a declaration is expected, not everywhere where you can use an expression.

The following is not an *expression* or an *expression-statement*, it is a *declaration*. (Technically, in C++, it can form a *declaration-statement* when used where a statement is expected, in C it is just a *declaration*.) Note that there is no *assignment-expression* sub-part to this declaration, `= 3` is an initializer for the declared entity `num`.

```
int num = 3;
```

These two common uses of `=` (initialization and assignment) are sometimes confused. Where `=` is being used to initialize the entity being declared in a declaration, it is initialization, where it is being used to change the value of an already declared entity, it is assignment.

Here is where C and C++ differ: in C, the parenthesised entity immediately following the `while` keyword must be an *expression* so something like `while (int num = 0) { /* ... */ }` is not valid.

In C++ the entity can be a *condition*, which allows for a simple declaration with an initializer as well as a simple *expression*, as in C. In C++, where the *condition* is in the form of a declaration, the declared entity is initialized on each iteration and implicitly converted to `bool` to determine whether to execute the loop body.

The `for` loop is special in both languages. In both languages the first part of the parenthesized list following the `for` keyword can effectively be either a *declaration* or an *expression-statement*.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop takes three expressions in C and C++. The first is executed before the loop is run. The value of the second is used to determine when the loop ends. The third expression is executed at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop.

You *can* abuse the intent of the `for` loop and put whatever expression you want in those three sections.

The while loop `while(<expression>) {<body>}` is equivalent to the for loop `for(;<expression>;) {<body>}`.

Comment: But the middle statement of a for must be convertable to a bool.

Comment: Now i only confuse whether initialization is an expression or not since assigment statement is an expression